# How can I delete a binary tree with O(1) additional memory?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I was wondering if it's possible to delete a binary tree with O(1) additional memory, without using recursion or stacks.

I have managed to write the naive, recursive postorder traversal solution (which uses stack memory):

```
void deleteTreeRec(Node *root)
{
   if (root == NULL) return;
   deleteTreeRec(root->left);
   deleteTreeRec(root->right);
   cout << "Deleting node " << root->data << endl;
   delete root;
}
```

I've heard that this can be achieved using (inorder) Morris traversal, which seems wrong, or at least counterintuitive, given the fact that tree deletion requires, as far as I understand, traversal in a postorder fashion (start by deleting the two subtrees, and only afterwards, the root). However, I haven't found any detailed description/pseudocode of the solution, hence I am trying my luck here.

If anybody could shed some light on this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the deletion the existing nodes of the binary tree can be used as a singly linked list: The nodes always using the `left` "link" is seen as the linked list.

To delete all nodes you simply repeat the following steps:

1. find the tail of the "linked list"
2. if `right` is non-null, move it to the end of the "list"
3. store the pointer the next element in the "list" in a temporary
4. replace the old head with the temporaty and repeat if the "list" is non-empty

Starting the search for the new tail at the previous tail results in the algorithm running in `O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes in the binary tree.

```
void deleteTree(Node* root)
{
    Node* tail = root;
    while (root != nullptr)
    {
        // update tail
        while (tail->left != nullptr)
        {
            tail = tail->left;
        }

        // move right to the end of the "list"
        // needs to happen before retrieving next, since the node may only have a right subtree
        tail->left = root->right;

        // need to retrieve the data about the next
        Node* next = root->left;

        delete root;

        root = next;
    }
}
```